# Try Catch Block Not Catching Exception

Tags: apex, trigger, exception

```
    trigger ServiceEnquiryOwnershipTrigger on Service_Enquiry__c (before insert) {

       System.debug('~~~ Begin');

        Set<String> accset = new Set<String>();

        for(Service_Enquiry__c s : Trigger.new)
        {
            accset.add(s.Account__c);
        }


        Map<Id,Account> accMap = new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT ID,OwnerId FROM Account WHERE ID IN :accSet]); 
        for(Service_Enquiry__c s : Trigger.New)
        {
            System.debug('~~~ Inside Loop');

          try
          {
                      if(s.Account__c != null)
                      {
                           System.debug('~~~ Account Match Found');
                           s.OwnerId = accMap.get(s.Account__c).OwnerId;
                           System.debug('~~~ Owner Id = '+s.OwnerId);

                      }
                      else
                      {
                          System.debug('~~ Account Not Found');
//BELOW LINE THROWS EXCEPTION
                          s.OwnerId = SEMapping__c.getValues(s.Lead_Office__c).Manager__c;
                          System.debug('~~~ Owner Id = '+s.OwnerId);

                      }
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
             System.debug('~~~ Inside Exception');
              s.OwnerId = SEMapping__c.getValues('Default').Manager__c;
              System.debug('~~~ Owner Id = '+s.OwnerId);
              s.System_Comments__c = 'Exception occured while assigning ownership';
          }
        }

        System.debug('~~~ End');
    }
```

As commented in the code snippet I get an exception at the line

```
s.OwnerId = SEMapping__c.getValues(s.Lead_Office__c).Manager__c;
```

In that custom settings I have knowingly put an inactive user to trigger an exception. In the catch block i intended to get a default user (who will always be active) and keep that as owner whenever there is an exception.
The exception is indeed getting thrown but for some reason it is not being caught by the "catch" block.

Let us assume inactive user as XXX and the default active user as YYY

The following occurs (obtained from the debug log)

```
~~~ Begin
~~~ Inside Loop
~~ Account Not Found
~~~ Owner Id = XXX
~~~ End
```

What I expected (when there is an exception)

```
~~~ Begin
~~~ Inside Loop
~~ Account Not Found
~~~ Owner Id = XXX
~~~ Inside Exception
~~~ Owner Id = YYY
~~~ End
```

I get the following exception

```
13:20:02.0 (280750383)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, operation performed with inactive user [XXX] as owner of 01Ip0000000Ck3E: []
```

Can someone tell me what I am missing ?

Comment: found out what the issue was...actually the exception DOES NOT occur at the place mentioned in the trigger. All I do in that code snippet is ASSIGN the s.OwnerId but actually the SAVE operation does not happen at that step. So the exception does not even occur at this specific place but rather happens when the actually save happens..I hope I am not confusing

Comment: you are right Aaron. here's a similar thread which has bit more detail on this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29451/proper-placement-of-try-catch-blocks

Comment: Please answer your own question then, Aaron.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Order of Execution.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) all before trigger run, then DML happens and then after trigger runs. Now in your case the DML happens after the execution of before insert trigger. Thus try catch block is useless here(It can catch only null ptr execption)

In Your code its asigning ownerID as Null/Inactive owner,but DML is yet to be performed thus the catch block wont run.

You should use try catch block from main code where the actual DML operation starts.

```
try{
  insert yourRecord;
}catch(Exception e){

//your code
}
```

> DML exceptions should always be handled from place where the actual
>   DML statement was called.

Answer (score 0):

There is noting wrong with your code. The thing is we can not catch all exception for ex. governor limit or the one your getting.

The best way to handle your exception is to make sure all new owners are assigning are active. 
Ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling

Comment: Whole execution breaks when there is Governor Exception, as we can see the last debug gets printed, thus it isnt governor exception(Its DML exception), I feel its logical error.